# Cyborg Rumble Pad V.5 not Recognized by Windows 7 (64 bit)

Tags: technical-issues, controllers, windows-7

I have bought a [Cyborg Rumble Pad V.5](http://www.cyborggaming.com/prod/cyborgpad.htm), but it isn't recognized by my operating system (Windows 7 64bit Home Premium - French).

I have downloaded the drivers from [Saitek's website](http://www.cyborggaming.com/download.htm) but the setup gets stuck, and it wouldn't recognize the controller.

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem, please ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried using a USB port that you know works?

Comment: yes, I tried them all

Comment: I also tried what MadCatz has suggested in here http://support.madcatz.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/140/27/my-usb-device-is-not-working--what-can-i-do but it didn't work either.

Comment: If it may help identify the problem, I've just tried the controller on a friend's Windows 7 32bit-system and it worked just fine: it was recognized as a gamepad and I could test the buttons/axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved ! :D

Surprisingly, I found [a solution in another manufacturer's website](http://support.pdp.com/ics/support/default.asp?deptID=5553) xD

So, if someone else have a similar problem to mine, here's what should be done (most of it is taken from the link):

1. Install the [Xbox 360 Accessories Software](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/d/xbox-360-controller-for-windows) for your specific OS.
2. Restart the computer.
3. Plug in your controller.
4. Open the "Device manager" (you should notice the yellow triangle near the controller's entry, in my case, the entry name is "Saitek Cyborg Pad for PC/Xbox 360 (HID)")
5. Right-click on the controller's entry > "Update driver software".
6. Click "Browse my computer for driver software" from the pop-up window.
7. Click "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer" from the next window.
8. Scroll down to and double click "Microsoft Common Controller For Windows Class".
9. Select "XBOX 360 Controller For Windows" from the list and click the "Next" button (for me, several entries matched that name, I chose the first one).
10. Click the "Yes" button on the "Update Driver Warning" window.
11. You should now have a new entry in the Device manager's "Microsoft Common Controller For Windows Class".
12. Almost there! If you open the Window's "standard" gamepad control panel and use the controller... nothing would happen (for me, at least, nothing happened :p )
13. Unplug the controller.
14. Run Saitek's drivers which can be downloaded from [their website](http://www.cyborggaming.com/download.htm).
15. When it asks to plug the controller in, do it, then, hopefully, the "Next" button wouldn't be grayed, so you can click it.
16. Follow the rest of the setup procedure.
17. Enjoy one of the best game controllers ever made :)

---

Bonus track: if you want to do more with the Cyborg Rumble Pad (it should also work for any other game controller in general) check these two links: [Xpadder](http://www.freewarefiles.com/xpadder_program_21789.html) and [XBox 360 Controller Emulator](http://www.x360ce.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Well in my situation (win7 x64 ps2700 rumble pad) the way you followed not exactly worked. So i tried sign over HID device etc. well after spending a lot of time found a really easy solution.. getting drivers from another site :D i gues saitek put ps3200 driver instead ps 2700 to their site so check other websites for correct drivers for your product. 
http://www.driverscape.com/manufacturers/saitek/input-devices/page3
worked for me best. when you re in download page ignore the advertise download link, follow the links below it. Well if this site doesnt work for you all i say is find the correct drivers for your product instead of spending time at device manager. When u you find it next button appears with no problem. So its not a driver problem its about finding the correct one :)